# Serial COM port output

Tags: io, serial-port, port, ports

I got a little question here.
I'm making a little weather station, and I'm trying to read the data in visual studio.

In arduino it looks like this

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2uzbknm.jpg

But when i try to read it in in Visual studio I get this

http://i59.tinypic.com/2rykccn.jpg

This is the code I have and I already think where the problem is, but I dont know how to solve it ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WeatherStation
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void PrintString(String data);
    public PrintString printDelegate;
    private SerialPort port;
    private char[] data;
    private int index;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new char[128];
        index = 0;
        printDelegate = new PrintString(PrintData);

    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8);
            port.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
            port.Open();

        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }

    }
    private void PrintData(String data)
    {
        txtBoxData.AppendText(" " + data + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            data[index] = (char)port.ReadByte();
            if (data[index] == '\n' )
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(printDelegate, new object[] { new String(data) });
                }

                index = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exc) //!!
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem is in this part with the '\n' but as i said before, I have no idea how to solve it.

```
            data[index] = (char)port.ReadByte();
            if (data[index] == '\n' )
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Using `new String(data)` is quite wrong, you only want data[0] .. data[index].  The second \n you get prints the entire content of data[] again instead of just \n.  Instead use `new String(data, 0, index+1)`, whether you include the \n in the string is up to you.  Or just use port.ReadLine() so you read the entire string in one whack.

Comment: Thanks i did the port.ReadLine() thing and now it works. I did also split the strings so i have only the values showing, but how can I use these values for other things, like using in a graph or something. I need an int or double so i can work with them..

This is the code i have now for DataReceivedHandler 

http://codepad.org/ymdH98e6